# Why the y axis in my barplot doesn't show completely?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I don't know how to change the code so that the y-axis in the barPlot shows completely? I expect it to show up to 10 as I have a 9.2 in my data points but it shows only up to 8. Any idea what's the hack to this?

Here's the code:
[image]

And here's what it shows:
[image]

Comment: set the `ylim` as you have set the `xlim`

Comment: Can you please make this as an answer ?

Comment: @rawr also do you know why there's not a black line shown for the x-axis like how it is shown for the y-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the `ylim = c(0, 10)` like the way you changed the `xlim`

Whatever the axis that the groups go on isn't drawn by default, so a vertical bar plot won't have x-axis; horizontal won't have y-axis. You can add that of course. Use the return value of `barplot`:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
bp <- barplot(c(8, 5), width = .5, main = 'Feature Exploration', xlim = c(0,4), ylim = c(0, 10),
              ylab = 'Errors (%)', xlab = 'ML Models', col = c('gray27','orangered4'))

## this will draw the x-axis but at points 1, 2, 3, ... which is not
## where the centers of your bars are plotted; you get that info in bp
axis(1)

bp <- barplot(c(8, 5), width = .5, main = 'Feature Exploration', xlim = c(0,4), ylim = c(0, 10),
              ylab = 'Errors (%)', xlab = 'ML Models', col = c('gray27','orangered4'))

## so try again with a fancy axis, bp is a matrix containing the centers
## of the plotted bars
axis(1, at = bp, labels = c('Model1','Model2'), lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = 1, tcl = -.5)
```

[image]